# Is it possible to setup a generic stream/view for building releases from any baseline?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is there a way to set up a single stream/view that can be used to build releases from any existing baseline (new and old) on any stream of a ClearCase UCM project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually use is a base ClearCase dynamic view, in order to quickly change baselines in its config spec.
A baseline is a label put on every files of a component, so the config spec would be:

```
element /vob/Component/... MY_BASELINE
element * /main/LATEST
```

Note that it will only work with fully labeled baselines (and not incremental baselines)

You can use also a snapshot view, for the compilation will be quicker (but you will have to support the update download time)

Comment: Can you have a base ClearCase dynamic view on an integration stream of a UCM project?

Comment: @Raihan: no the idea behind a single base ClearCase view is to be able to reuse it at will, changing the baseline within its config spec. But this is for reading the elements only, not for associating it with a Stream like an UCM view does (because the UCM view needs to configure the mkbranch rule after the stream name in case of checkout). You don't have to make any checkout with that compilation view.